# Removing event listener that invokes an event listener

Tags: javascript, d3.js, addeventlistener

Note: there are a lot of questions related to removing event listeners.
In the simple case they are solved by moving the anonymous JS function to a named one and then calling the function `removeEventListener` with the specified name.

e.g.

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(event){console.log("you clicked me");)})
```

goes to

```
function youClickedMe(event) {console.log("you clicked me");}
element.addEventListener("click", youClickedMe)
```

and then elsewhere

```
element.removeEventListener("click", youClickedMe)
```

---

In my case, it is a bit more complex.

1. I have a closed variable that I need to pass along
2. my event binds new event listeners

I am tying to create capture what the user does when the left mouse button (LMB) is clicked and the mouse moves over a certain area after the DOM has entered a certain mode (a button is pressed, toggling a boolean)

So far it works pretty ok, see fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/SumNeuron/o1yu8oyt/

but the event "mousemove" will not go away no matter what I try.

Further, when I add a `d3.zoom` / `d3.pan` function to the mix, things get even worse... but that is a separate question.

Any ideas on how to remove this / these added event(s)?

Comment: The problem is that when you're ubinding the event listener you no longer have a reference to the function you bound it to. (Because each time you call the handler you're creating a new mousedown function). Why not just have a global variable that tells you the state (i.e. that the toggle is ON, and presumably, the index of the color array)?

Comment: @jake2389 so if I move the `mouseDownAndMove` outside of the function then it might work? Good question. The content is has this functionality is dynamically created and removed, so there can be multiple instances that all act on the same svg... in the closure that makes them, I have a global toggle var, but that doesnt help with the functions needing some local variables...

Comment: I was actually talking about the `mousedown` function in line 38, but it's also the case for the `mouseDownAndMove`. If you're dynamically creating and destroying these then a closure might not be the best idea as you could end up with some serious [memory leaks](https://medium.com/@yurachoi/whats-a-memory-leak-i-forget-b27fc8201b) from using them

Comment: @jake2389 good points. I'll try to restructure accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546537/d3-and-js-removing-event-listener-that-invokes-an-event-listener#comment88103907_50546537), you're referencing different functions here.

If, for whatever reason, you cannot refactor your code and logic, you can simply pass `null` as the D3 selection's listener:

```
svg.on('mousedown', null)
```

By the way, in a D3 code, using D3 methods is way more convenient than using pure JS ones.

Here is the code with that change:

```js
// toggle events with button
d3.select("button").on("click", toggle)
// for convenience
var svg = d3.select("svg")
// some external vars, could be closure vars...
var counter = 0;
var colors = ["red", "coral", "black", "white"]


function toggle(d, i) {

  var btn = d3.select(this)
  var activeQ = btn.classed("active")
  // toggle
  activeQ = !activeQ
  btn.classed("active", activeQ)

  // I have something like this in my code, and could be 
  // the route of the bug... but here for completeness
  var closedVar = "I can only be (easily) calculated here, but am needed in the event";

  if (activeQ) {
    // new toggle, start counter over
    counter = 0
    svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
  } else {
    // remove the mouse down event
    svg.on('mousedown', null)
    // could clean up svg here, but for demo purposes leave it

    // maybe custom event to cleanup elsewhere?
    /* svg.dispatch("cleanup") */
  }

  // this function can use the local var closedVar
  // and be named in addEventListener
  function mousedown(event) {
    dropPoints(event, closedVar)
  }

}


function dropPoints(event, closedVar) {
  // want to only trigger on mouse down and move
  var pts = []
  svg.on('mousemove', mouseDownAndMove)
  svg.on('mouseup', function(event) {
    counter += 1;
    svg.on('mousemove', null)
  })


  /* svg.node().addEventListener('cleanup', function(event) {
    svg.node().removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseDownAndMove, true)
  }) */

  function mouseDownAndMove() {
    // event.which === 1 for mouse events ~might~ be left mouse button... at least in jQuery
    if (d3.event.which != 1) {
      return
    }

    var pt = d3.mouse(svg.node())

    svg.append("circle").attr("r", 3).attr("fill", colors[counter % (colors.length)])
      .attr("cx", pt[0])
      .attr("cy", pt[1])


  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<style>
  svg {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  
  .active {
    background-color: coral;
  }
</style>

<button>
Click to activate
</button>

<svg id="demo" width="500" height="500" style="background-color:blue;">
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I was able to refractor. It is not in its final form, but you can test out the thing I made here: https://sumneuron.gitlab.io/d3sm/demos/scatter/index.html I think you might like it. +1 for a working solution (although I already fixed my own code). As much as I like d3, I think vanilla JS event handler is ~maybe~ better? I have had issues with binding events in d3 that I did not have in vanilla js... although it could just be my inexperience with `d3.on` and associated functions

Comment: Well, D3 is a JS library, so any vanilla JS will work in a D3 code. But most of the times it's not the most convenient or idiomatic way.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/jgv37zzk/

I tried moving some stuff around. A key thing is that the `removeEventsListener` was not working because you were setting the `useCapture` flag to `true`, but did not set it as well in the `addEventListener`.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with the `dropPoints` function (since, right now, it only *binds* the event listener), but if you provide more context I might be able to update the answer.

Comment: +1 as you set me on the right path to answer my question; however the linked fiddle suffers the same issue as my original fiddle. The `dropPoints` function is there as that is how my code (not the MWE) encountered this bug. So I was not sure if it was this function that was to blame. But after refractoring it works like a charm :) Thank you very much